# An issue about UDP server

Tags: c#, udp, multicast

I'm developing a client/server application in C#. And it often sends the same packet to many endpoints. It's clearly terrible that the same data is copied to OS buffer and cause some other problems. As far as I'm concerned, I just couldn't come up with a effective way to finish the work. I've thought about multicast, is that available on the Internet? If so, how do I use it? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Multicast doesn't work on the Internet (for the moment, maybe it'll come in the future).

Comment: I see, but it's not necessary to use multicast. I just wonder how to avoid the unnecessary copying operation from app buffer to OS buffer.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: The designer of OS shall provide a effective way to do, it's really costly.

Answer (score 0):

`Unicast` to every connected client, their session may runs on a own thread. And verify that `UDP` is really what you want/need.

Comment: It sometimes is, but packets like notifications commonly need to be posted to several clients. And it caused the problem.